# Are errors emitted as logs on the blockchain?

Tags: events, error, blocks, logs

Say if an error is caused due to a revert statement will it be emitted as an event so front end application will be aware or not?

Answer (score 0):

If a transaction reverts the cause isn't recorded as a log entry. Only the status is recorded as a failure.

The revert value is available but it isn't recorded in the block.